# I can't run more than 5 queues in my Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, plesk, supervisord, laravel-queue

I have implemented Queues in a Laravel project. Since I can't install Supervisor on my server, I launch the `queue:work` command for each queue in Plesk panel. It works fine until I exceed 5 queues. The jobs in the 6th queue and above are saved in the database but the code is not executed. What could be the reason?

Comment: are the jobs finishing or hanging ? it's a queue, so for the 6th job to start you need the previous X jobs to finish first (X depends on configuration, usually one).

Comment: What's your configuration of the `config/queue.php` file?

Comment: @N69S I said the 6th "queue" not job. Queues are executed in parallel.

Comment: @Md.ZayedHassan database

Comment: You should check if there is a limit on the maximum number of processes or workers that can be executed simultaneously on your server. It could be set to 5.